# Configure environment for React Native / Fastlane app

Tags: git, react-native, configuration, environment-variables, fastlane

I have a [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) app (iOS and Android) that I need to build for two clients. I want to replace the logo and colours of the app at build time.

Some options I've considered:

- Branch/fork the repository. Problem: more work to maintain two versions.
- Keep assets outside of source tree to be provided at build time. Problem: trickier to set up, especially with CI (?)
- Check all assets in and switch between them with an environment variable. Problem: don't know how to set environment variable when app runs on the device. Also it's not scalable, but for now that's OK.

How can I parameterise a React Native app, particularly one deployed with [Fastlane](https://fabric.io/features/distribution)? .. maybe by passing parameters [like this](https://docs.fastlane.tools/advanced/#passing-parameters)?

Comment: I would go with the 3rd option, but I do not know how you build. Do you have your own CI and you can create two different jobs that pass in the corresponding parameters? I created a GitHub repo for an article that discusses this, perhaps this helps? https://github.com/lyndsey-ferguson/medium-post-fastlane

Comment: @LyndseyFerguson Actually we had CI, but the server has been shut down :'( So, when we set it up again we can probably deal with that. I tried going with the 3rd option first, but dealing with the native assets (icons for Android and iOS) was hard - it would require a special build step to replace the assets based on the variable. So for now I'm reluctantly going with option 1. I'll probably switch to option 2 in future.

Comment: Okay. We use #3 to deal with dozens of customers with their own artwork and custom parameters. We do have a built-up set of fastlane actions and it is a pretty nice system. If you do revisit option #3 later, let me know if you run into any obstacles.

Answer (score 1):

One possible setup includes:

1. Add the `react-native-config` package to your ReactNative project (https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config)
2. Setup `.env.someEnv` files in your ReactNative project (the above package uses these)
3. Setup your variables for images paths etc based on the desired environment
4. Do the required setup work as per the packages readme, including needing to run the command `echo .env.client1 > /tmp/envfile` prior to build. There are a few options for this including:

   a. setup a package script in your package.json file and run the command prior to your fast lane command, e.g. `echo .env.client1 /tmp/envile && bundle exec fastlane ios release`

   b. Bit trickier but setup xcconfig files for your different environments in your Xcode project and have a variable in there called ENVFILE. Then tell fastlane to use the correct xcconfig file through the `xcconfig` param in `gym`. Finally setup a pre-build action in your Xcode scheme with the command `echo $ENVFILE > /tmp/envfile`

Apologies don't have time for a more detailed write up, feel free to reply should you like more details and I will help where I can.

Comment: This was really helpful